# I "just" watched the movie last week. - can just be used with a time verb like yesterday, last week, etc.?

Tags: tense

**Example 1**

> I just watched the movie last week.

**Example 2**

> I recently watched the movie last week.

I know just and recently can be used with verbs in simple past, but can they be used with a time adverb like yesterday, last week, etc.?

Answer (score 1):

Your second example doesn't work well because it is redundant. "Last week" specifies when you watched the movie, so there is no need to say "recently". Therefore, the sentence sounds unnatural.

Although the same reasoning might seem to apply to your first example, "just" is often used to emphasize that an event has occurred recently. For example:

> I just watched the movie last week, so I don't want to watch it again.
> I just watched the movie last week, but I can't remember the name of the main character!

Therefore, the first sentence is fine.

Answer (score 0):

"Recently" and "last week" are both *adverbs of time*. Only one adverb of time can modify a clause, so your second sentence is bad grammar. You either watched the movie recently, or you watched it last week, not both.

"Just" in that context in an adverb roughly meaning "only", which fits well with "last week", so your first sentence is fine. You can tell that "just" isn't an adverb of time because you cannot say either of these:

> <del>I watched the movie **just**.</del>"
> "<del>**Just**, I watched the movie.</del>"